# ASP.NET MVC 5 EF Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails

Tags: c#, database, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5

I've a thread which contains a startpost as part of the thread-content. It also includes a list of replys, which are also posts.

```
class Post {
    [Key]
    public int Id{get;set;}
    public DateTime CreationDate{get;set;}
    public virtual string Content{get;set;}
    public int ThreadId{get;set;}
    public virtual Thread Thread{get;set;}
}

class Thread {
    [Key]
    public int Id{get;set;}
    public string Title{get;set;}
    public int FirstPostId{get;set;}
    public virtual Post FirstPost{get;set;}
    public List<Post> Replys{get;set;}
}
```

When a thread is created i simply add them to the DbContext and save it. This works without issues. But if a reply is submitted, I add them to the post-list and mark the entity of the thread as modified like this

```
var db = new MyContext();
var thread = db.Threads.Where(thread => thread.Id = threadId).FirstOrDefault();
thread.Replys.Add(newPost);
db.Entry<Thread>(thread).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Modified;
db.SaveChanges();
```

Here is the problem that I get a violation of the foreignkey on Thread.FirstPost:

> Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails ("MyTable"."posts", CONSTRAINT "Thread_FirstPost" FOREIGN KEY ("Id") REFERENCES "threads" ("Id") ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION)

I found many information about this. In short, all say, that this is related to the default behavior of EF that checks the integrity. So when a Thread has to be deleted it depends on the FirstPost which has also to be deleted but this depends on the Thread which seem to confuse EF.

The internet has 2 solutions for this problem: Using fluent-API to disable cascade for the entity using `.WillCascadeOnDelete(false);` or disable it completely by removing the convention. I tried both ways:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder) {
        //base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<OneToManyCascadeDeleteConvention>();
        modelBuilder.Entity<Thread>()
            .HasOptional(t => t.FirstPost)
            .WithRequired()
            .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Post>()
            .HasOptional(p => p.Thread)
            .WithMany()
            .HasForeignKey(p => p.ThreadId)
            .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
}
```

But nothing is working, I get the same exception than before. I have no idea why, and it seems that all others which had this problem could solve it by using one of those methods, but in my case both have no effect...

**Table-Definitions from Visual Studio Server-Explorer**

```
CREATE TABLE `posts` (
  `Id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `CreationDate` datetime NOT NULL,
  `Content` longtext NOT NULL,
  `ThreadId` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`Id`),
  KEY `ThreadId` (`ThreadId`),
  CONSTRAINT `Thread_Post` FOREIGN KEY (`Id`) REFERENCES `threads` (`Id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `Thread_Replys` FOREIGN KEY (`ThreadId`) REFERENCES `threads` (`Id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1

CREATE TABLE `threads` (
  `Id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `Title` longtext NOT NULL,
  `PostId` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `ViewsCount` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `IsClosed` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `IsVisible` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `ReplysCount` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`Id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `Id` (`Id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

**Table-Definition generated by EF (from Database-Server)**

```
CREATE TABLE `Posts`(
    `Id` int NOT NULL, 
    `CreationDate` datetime NOT NULL, 
    `Content` longtext NOT NULL, 
    `ThreadId` int NOT NULL
)
ALTER TABLE `Posts` ADD PRIMARY KEY (Id)
ALTER TABLE `Posts` ADD CONSTRAINT Thread_Post
ALTER TABLE `Posts` ADD KEY (`ThreadId`)
ALTER TABLE `Posts` ADD CONSTRAINT Thread_Replys
ALTER TABLE `Posts` ADD CONSTRAINT Thread_Post
    FOREIGN KEY (Id)
    REFERENCES `Threads` (Id)
ALTER TABLE `Posts` ADD CONSTRAINT Thread_Replys
    FOREIGN KEY (ThreadId)
    REFERENCES `Threads` (Id)
ALTER TABLE `Posts` ADD CONSTRAINT Thread_Replys
    FOREIGN KEY (ThreadId)
    REFERENCES `Threads` (Id)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION

CREATE TABLE `Threads`(
    `Id` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT UNIQUE, 
    `Title` longtext NOT NULL, 
    `PostId` int NOT NULL, 
    `ViewsCount` int NOT NULL, 
    `IsClosed` bool NOT NULL, 
    `IsVisible` bool NOT NULL, 
    `ReplysCount` int NOT NULL
)
ALTER TABLE `Threads` ADD PRIMARY KEY (Id)
```

Here are some pages I found on my research to this topic:
http://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/associations-in-ef-code-first-ctp5-part-3-one-to-one-foreign-key-associations

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/368164/EF-Data-Annotations-and-Code-Fluent

http://geekswithblogs.net/danemorgridge/archive/2010/12/17/ef4-cpt5-code-first-remove-cascading-deletes.aspx

http://patrickdesjardins.com/blog/entity-framework-4-3-delete-cascade-with-code-first-poco

[ASP.NET MVC 4 Multiple Foreign Keys Referencing Single Parent Entity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12926675/asp-net-mvc-4-multiple-foreign-keys-referencing-single-parent-entity)

http://www.davepaquette.com/archive/2012/09/15/whered-my-data-go-andor-how-do-i-get-rid-of-it.aspx

http://czetsuya-tech.blogspot.de/2012/01/specify-on-delete-no-action-or-on.html#.Viy-0X54u9J

[Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths - why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17127351/introducing-foreign-key-constraint-may-cause-cycles-or-multiple-cascade-paths)

[Entity Framework: how to solve "FOREIGN KEY constraint may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14489676/entity-framework-how-to-solve-foreign-key-constraint-may-cause-cycles-or-multi)

[Specify ON DELETE NO ACTION in ASP.NET MVC 4 C# Code First](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12868912/specify-on-delete-no-action-in-asp-net-mvc-4-c-sharp-code-first)

Comment: it says the FOREIGN KEY constraint fails, it has nothing to do with cascade on delete. when you add an entry to the database, you just have to ensure that all FK's are matching the keys on the navigation properties they are referencing (even when they are getting changed later, they have to be set to the same temporary value)

Comment: I edited some pages I found during research to this error. I think that the point here is UPDATE and not delete, because I don't delete data, I update the thread. The FKs are fine, after creating the thread EF is loading the FirstPost correctly with the Id 1. That's the reason why I can't understand this error - I think that I've to specify an action for update instead of NO ACTION, but I can't figure out how to do this.

Comment: I think it just mentions the full constraint that fails upon insertion.

Comment: in the thread class, try to add `[ForeignKey("FirstPostId")]`above the `public virtual Post FirstPost{get;set;}`
you'll need to use `using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;` for that

Comment: This gave me the error that the FK wasn't found in the Post-Model. I thought it shoult be [ForeignKey("FirstPost")] and above the FirstPostId attibute, but this isn't working. @DevilSuichiro Sorry but I can't relly understand what you want to say.

Comment: I can't even create a database from your model because the foreign keys aren't nullable. Is this your working model?

Comment: Yes, its working. I can create a thread without any problem. Only when I try to reply to a thread, I get the quoted error above. Have you also inserted the fluent api directives in my `OnModelCreating` method? Without them I can't even create a thread. Btw I also tried to make the FKs nullable, but without  effect.

Comment: Yes I did, but in Sql Server. Apparently the query providers have different model validations.

Answer (score 0):

Your foreign keys are not set properly, it's ok not to define a foreign key explicitly in case you user the original class name, I'll explain it on your code:

```
class Post {
    [Key]
    public int Id{get;set;}
    public DateTime CreationDate{get;set;}
    public virtual string Content{get;set;}
    public int ThreadId{get;set;}  **-> here you used ThreadId which is implicitly a foreignkey for Thread, and that's good**
    public virtual Thread Thread{get;set;}
}

class Thread {
    [Key]
    public int Id{get;set;}
    public string Title{get;set;}
    public int FirstPostId{get;set;} **-> here you can do the same by changing this to PostId**
    public virtual Post FirstPost{get;set;} **-> and this to Post**
    public List<Post> Replys{get;set;}
}
```

Or you have a better option of using data annotations:

Replace this:

```
 public virtual Post FirstPost{get;set;}
```

with this:

```
[ForeignKey("FirstPostId")]
public virtual Post FirstPost{get;set;}
```

This is telling EF that `FirstPostId` is the foreignkey for `FirstPost.

Let me know if that worked.

**UPDATE**

I've changed your sql code manually and it works now:

```
CREATE TABLE threads (
  Id int NOT NULL,
  Title nvarchar(max) NOT NULL,
  PostId int,
  ViewsCount int NOT NULL,
  IsClosed tinyint NOT NULL,
  IsVisible tinyint NOT NULL,
  ReplysCount int NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (Id),
) 

CREATE TABLE posts (
  Id int NOT NULL,
  CreationDate datetime NOT NULL,
  Content nvarchar(max) NOT NULL,
  ThreadId int NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (Id),
  CONSTRAINT Thread_Post FOREIGN KEY (Id) REFERENCES threads (Id) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT Thread_Replys FOREIGN KEY (ThreadId) REFERENCES threads (Id) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
)

ALTER TABLE threads ADD CONSTRAINT Post_Thread FOREIGN KEY (PostId) REFERENCES posts (Id) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
```

You can't define thread to require postID, and post to require threadID at the same time, if you do you won't be able to create either (unless you create both at the same time - meaning in the same db.savechanges()).

Think about it. you want to define a thread using a post that doesn't exists yet.

Comment: I renamed `Thread.FirstPostId` to `Thread.PostId` => No effect, again "Cannot add or update a child row..." error. Using the ForeignKey-Attribute I get an exception that the attribute is invalid because PostId wasn't found in the Post-Model. I think the attribute should be `ForeignKey("FirstPost")` and placed above `PostId` - Then the exception of the invalid attribute is gone, but then I get again the "Cannot add or update a child row" exception because of the FK `FirstPost` :(

Comment: if you try renaming the fields, also rename `FirstPost` to `Post`.
Can you also post your db tables definition?

Comment: I renamed the FirstPost-Attribute, but still the same. You can see the defintion generated by EF here: https://u-img.net/view/6007Yn.png

Comment: You mean the plain SQL to generate the tables?

Comment: you supplied the code before your fluent API changes.
in visual studio -> open server explorer -> connect to your db -> right on a table -> click open table definition -> there you can see the code.

try to load it [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/)

Comment: I think I found what you want. I edited it in my question under the point "Table-Definitions from Visual Studio Server-Explorer". SQL Fiddle works for the Thread-table: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/218544/1 But for the Post-Table I also get the error "Cannot add foreign key constraint" which make it not possible to save it.

Comment: oh. just noticed it (wow took me some time) you have a constraint for foreign key in both tables.. that's impossible. In order to create a Post you need a threadID, inorder to create a thread you need a postID. you need to set one of them as nullable

Answer (score 0):

The root problem is that your model contains a 1:1 association between `Post` and `Thread` in which `Thread` is the principle, or independent, entity. This is expressed by the part ...

```cs
modelBuilder.Entity<Thread>()
    .HasOptional(t => t.FirstPost)
    .WithRequired()
```

You see it reflected in the DDL statement ...

```sql
ALTER TABLE `Posts` ADD CONSTRAINT Thread_Post
    FOREIGN KEY (Id)
    REFERENCES `Threads` (Id)
```

So `Post's` primary key is *also* a foreign key to `Thread`. This means that you can't ever insert more than one `Post` per `Thread`! (Because each subsequent `Post` necessarily should have a new PK value, but that doesn't refer to an existing `Thread` so you get constraint violations).

You could solve this (maybe) by making `Post` the principle entity. In that case, `Thread` would have a PK/FK combination referring to its first `Post`. However, to me, 1:1 associations convey that entities are strongly related to a point where they're almost one (`Student`-`StudentDetails`). So I don't think a 1:1 association is appropriate here anyway.

I would suggest this mapping:

```cs
modelBuilder.Entity<Thread>()
    .HasOptional(t => t.FirstPost)
    .WithMany()
    .HasForeignKey(t => t.FirstPostId)
    .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);

modelBuilder.Entity<Post>()
    .HasRequired(p => p.Thread)
    .WithMany(t => t.Replies)
    .HasForeignKey(p => p.ThreadId)
    .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
```

This theoretically turns the relationship between `Thread` and `FirstPost` into 1-to-many, but practically it means that `Thread` now has a foreign key to its first post, and these complicated PK/FK combinations are gone. Note that `FirstPostId` should be a nullable int to support this.

On the other hand, if in your opinion a `Thread` and its first post *are* closely related you could consider merging both into a thread that also has the attributes of its first post (`CreationDate`, `Content`). You'll end up with a very simple model of threads (posts?) with replies in which still nothing is redundant.

Comment: Your code gave me an error that a correct mapping between tasks can't be found - But I understand the reason of the issue now. My first approach was to use inheritance like you said (Thread inherit from Post). The mail problem with this is: I want to display later the newest content (so threads AND posts). This would be more easy and clear when the firstpost of a Thread is a Post, so I simply can query on the Post-Table ordered by CreationDate and grouped by ThreadId.

Comment: But as this isn't working, I will simply try to add a `LastPostTime` attribute to the thread, so that I simply can query the Thread-Table ordered by the LastPostTime. This will result in a bit of redundant information, but I see no better way to realize this.

Comment: You probably mean that EF can 't determine a correct ordering of inserts/updates? Yes, that could be an issue, you should probably save a `Thread` first. The advantage of a merged `Thread/FirstPost` class is that saving the thread and the post is an atomic operation (well, of course, it's one record).